# OrderBy a List of Dictionaries with StringComparison

Tags: c#, linq

So I have an implementation wherein a list of dictionaries are being sorted by according to their key.

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> queue = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
queue = queue.OrderBy(x => x[sortField]).ThenBy(x => x["WorkflowID"]).ToList();
```

Now, I am trying to add `StringComparison.IgnoreOrdinalCase` after the `[sortField]` but I am being returned with errors that it has some invalid arguments.

Is it not really possible to have a StringComparison with dictionaries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with dictionaries, you're calling the regular `OrderBy` LINQ method. It just happens to be on a dictionary.

I'm assuming you tried this:

```
queue.OrderBy(x => x[sortField], StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

And got an error, because `x[sortField]` returns an *object*, not a *string*. Thus, having an `IComparer<string>` against an `object` is invalid.

If you're sure 'sortField' will always point to a string value, then simply cast the value:

```
queue.OrderBy(x => (string)x[sortField], StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Will try this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`StringComparison` is a enum specific to some methods on `String`.  Generic LINQ methods have no way of operating on that enum.

You should use the `StringComparer` class instead, which exposes `IComparer<string>` instances with the same names that LINQ can accept.